# Timestamp is not generate

Tags: nestjs-config

```
 createdAt?: Date;
```

Here is my code on postInterface

```
@CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp", default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'})
    createdAt: Date;
```

Here is my code on postEntity.
And on my postgres database table, I selected timestamp without time zone.

Please I need you help